# The attendance at a school party is 17, 12,16, 14, 20, for Monday thru Friday. ..

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

The logics for this question is quite hard for me. I hope someone could help.

The attendance at a school party is 17, 12,16, 14, 20, for Monday thru Friday. What's the least number of student the school has, given that no student attended the party in two consecutive days?

Comment: I wish my school had a party 5 days a week ;-)

Comment: How does that involve combinatorics, and what is inclusion and exclusion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, let's work through this. I am going to assume that the numbers you listed were in order to match the different days.

Mon: 17

Tues: 12

Wed: 16

Thurs: 14

Fri: 20

We can simply get the answer by adding the two consecutive days that have the most number of attendees. This would be the lowest possible number of people the school has because we know the school will have AT LEAST that many people. The two consecutive days that have the most number of people is Thursday and Friday, which is 34 people.

**The school has a minimum of 34 people.**

Comment: But students who attended the party may be one of the people who attend on mon, tue, and wed. The sum of the three numbers is even larger.?

Comment: @Valkyrie This is true, but it doesn't _have_ to be true though. We have to assume that it is the lowest number of people possible. The lowest amount of people that it can be is 34, this would be if the people that attended Mon-Wed were only the people who attended Thurs-Fri. Again, we have to assume that this happened to get the minimum. Just like if we were getting the maximum where we would have to assume that each attendee was a different person.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly there must be as many as came on the two largest neighboring days.  Then can you show that is enough?

Comment: You mean 34, why though?

Comment: Why chose the numbers on the last two days?

Comment: Because there must be that many just to satisfy Thursday and Friday.  With a different set of data, where the two largest days were not neighbors, there could be other issues, but with this one we can show this works.